# Should I add Parameters to my URL outside of React Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using react router v4 and I have a page that has a few components on it.

1. Filter area
2. Results area
3. Ads

Now when a user checks off a checkbox(ie Ford), the results area should populate with results that have a manufacturer of Ford.

One requirement I have though is that I should be able to copy the url and then paste it in a new tab and the sameish results should show up.

I of course am going to do pretty much what everyone else does and add the criteria to the url

```
/results?manufacturer=Ford
```

I was going to use react router to do this

```
this.props.history.replace(path)
```

however this seems to cause a re-render of the page(including ComponentsDidMount) and I am wondering if it would not be more efficient to alter the url outside of react router to stop this re-render.

I will have to re-render either way as state will be changing when they do check a checkbox.

However I am wondering if doing it the react router way if I am causing more then what is needed to be rendered(ie, all the ComponentsDidMount will refire, everything on the page probably will re-render like the ad compoents???) as essentially it seems like I am almost refreshing the page.

Edit

I know whatever way I come up with I will have to handle someone copying in the url into new browser/tab of whatever and on load will have to read it.

My problem is right now when I do check a checkbox it seems by doing this line in my onChange handler

```
this.props.history.replace(path)
```

the page does a full refresh and this just seems inefficient to me.

I will try to make a codepen example but I am not sure how to setup all the libraries and stuff yet to make the example work.

Answer (score 0):

So really simply React Router goes out the window once you are copying the URL and pasting in a new tab, it's just not designed for that purpose.

To maintain results you could either:

1. Add a method in your constructor to grab params from the URL if they exist then automatically check the box and add the results.
2. Create dynamic routing for React Router, so that you can grab it a little easier out of `this.props.match.params` but you will still have to handle it on page load

Dynamic routes are a lot nicer though, if you aren't sure how to do them a simple is example would be:

1. Define your route as `search/:manufacturer/results`
2. On click of the box update your history to `/search/ford/results`
3. Check your `this.props.match.params.manufacturer` to get the value

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yep, I understand that I will need to capture it if someone copies the url and puts it in a new tab. My problem is that even if they are in the same tab as soon as I do a .push/replace the entire life cycle of the page seems to occur and to me this seems kinda inefficient.

Comment: With dynamic routes, I agree they are nicer but I am not sure how to handle multiple choices (ie they could do ford and honda would it look like /search/ford/hond/.../results). How about year ranges.

Comment: With that you wouldn't use dynamic routes, it's definitely a Query Params scenario when you have multiple choices like that.

Just pass them through the history as the user updates and it will show up in the URL bar... then on componentDidMount() parse the query string if there are any params and handle it accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below one.

```
this.props.history.push(`/search/ford/results`);
```

Or as you have said since you will checkbox, depending on that value you can do this:

```
this.props.history.push(`/search/${value}/results`);
```

You need to pass the checkbox value to the value. i.e., ford, etc.

I hope this would work for you.

Comment: won't these still do a full re-render(ie almost a full refresh of the page with the whole life cycle)

Comment: Also a user might check multiple manufacturers like (ford,honda,Toyota) also I am going to have X filters that change. So I am not sure doing it this way how I could put it dynamically.

Comment: Yes, you can add those values dynamically.

Comment: I mean use a loop and use that history.push dynamically for each condition.

Comment: but how would I make the route to match this? as it is not only making the "push" part the route has to match as well.